# How do I force a udp client socket received by a udp server to bind to a specific client port

Tags: c++, udp, winsock

I need to connect two programs via udp. The way this is to work is that both programs are udp servers and they send and receive on two ports like this:

programA listens on port 20037 and sends on port 20038. 
programB listens on port 20038 and sends on port 20037.

Both programA and programB run on the same computer.

programA is already written and it does appear to bind its sockets as above. ie transmit port = 20038 and listen port = 20037.

I have written a udp program to be programB.

My program B binds the server socket to port 20038 which is correct.

But when programB receives a message from programA, the client socket seems to bind to some random port, eg port 10690.  But I need it to bind to port 20037.

The protocol used, needs to send a simple ack message back when a message is received.

My code looks like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in client;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
/* Loop and get data from clients */
while (1)
{
    int client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    /* Receive bytes from client */
int bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);
if (bytes_received < 0)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not receive datagram.\n");
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("%u bytes received from client on port %u\n", bytes_received, client.sin_port);
    SendAck();
}
```

And SendAck() is like this:

```
void udpserver::SendAck() {

    unsigned char acker[] = { SOM, ACK };
    int length = sizeof(acker)/sizeof(acker[0]);

    int client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if (sendto(sd, (const char*)acker, length, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, client_length) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error transmitting data.\n");
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("successfully sent ack to client\n");
}
```

I assumed that port number of client socket received would be the 20037 but it is a random number.  Can I force the client socket to bind to port 20037?  Because the ack message has to be sent to port 20037.

And I can't change the design of this.  ProgramA will always bind to listening port 20037 and send by binding its client port to 20038.  I have freedom to do whatever is required for programB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recvfrom()` reports the remote IP/port that the received packet was sent from.  ProgramA is sending data from port 20038.  `SendAck()` is calling `sendto()` using the client information provided by `recvfrom()`, which means the ACK is being sent to port 20038, not to port 20037.

It is unusual for a UDP system to send replies to a port that is different than the sending port.  But so be it.  You will have to tell `sendto()` which port to send to.

You are also not logging the sender's port correctly.  The `client.sin_port` is expressed in network byte order.  Use `ntohs()` to change it to host byte order when logging it.  Failing to do that would account for the *random* number you are seeing.

Try this:

```
struct sockaddr_in client;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

/* Loop and get data from clients */
while (1)
{
    int client_length = (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    /* Receive bytes from client */
    int bytes_received = recvfrom(sd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_length);
    if (bytes_received < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not receive datagram.\n");
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("%u bytes received from client at %s on port %u\n", bytes_received, inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), ntohs(client.sin_port));

    SendAck(&client);
}
```

```
void udpserver::SendAck(struct sockaddr_in *client)
{
    struct sockaddr_in receiver;

    memcpy(&receiver, client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    receiver.sin_port = htons(20037);

    unsigned char acker[] = { SOM, ACK };
    int length = sizeof(acker)/sizeof(acker[0]);

    if (sendto(sd, (const char*)acker, length, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&receiver, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error transmitting data.\n");
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("successfully sent ack to client at %s on port %d\n", inet_ntoa(receiver.sin_addr), ntohs(receiver.sin_port));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind socket to port which you want to be used as an outbound port:

```
client.sin_port = htons(20037);
```

and then send:

```
sendto(sd, (const char*) acker, length, 0,
        (struct sockaddr*) &client, client_length);
```